# Criar um Read More com jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Olá, eu estou com um problema.
Tenho o seguinte código no jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/o7x14gzd/1/
para a criação de um botão de "leia mais" com jQuery.

Não sei onde está errado, mas quando o texto é muito grande, ele não mostra tudo ao clicar em "Read More".

Algum de vocês já enfrentou algo parecido ou podem me dizer onde está o erro?

Obrigado

---

Segue o código copiado do jsfiddle:

```js
var $el, $ps, $up, totalHeight;

$(".sidebar-box .button").click(function() {
      
  totalHeight = 0

  $el = $(this);
  $p  = $el.parent();
  $up = $p.parent();
  $ps = $up.find("p:not('.read-more')");
  
  // measure how tall inside should be by adding together heights of all inside paragraphs (except read-more paragraph)
  $ps.each(function() {
    totalHeight += $(this).outerHeight();
  });
        
  $up
    .css({
      // Set height to prevent instant jumpdown when max height is removed
      "height": $up.height(),
      "max-height": 9999
    })
    .animate({
      "height": totalHeight
    });
  
  // fade out read-more
  $p.fadeOut();
  
  // prevent jump-down
  return false;
    
});
```

```css
.sidebar-box {
  max-height: 150px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.sidebar-box .read-more { 
  position: absolute; 
  bottom: 0; 
  left: 0;
  width: 100%; 
  text-align: center; 
  margin: 0; padding: 30px 0; 
 
  /* "transparent" only works here because == rgba(0,0,0,0) */
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent, white);
}

.button {
   /*border-top: 1px solid #96d1f8;*/
   background: #FF9C00;
   /*background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#FF9C00), to(#ffce80));
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #FF9C00, #ffce80);*/
   padding: 5px 10px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
   -moz-border-radius: 5px;
   border-radius: 5px;
   
   
   /* overboard shadows for Opera (and why spec version listed first) */
   box-shadow: rgba(196, 196, 196, 1) 0 1px 10px, rgba(196, 196, 196, 1) 0 0 10px, rgba(196, 196, 196, 1) 0 0 10px, rgba(0,0,0,90) 0 0 10px;
   
   -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
   -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
    
   text-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,.4) 0 1px 0;
   color: white;
   font-size: 15px;
   font-family: Georgia, serif;
   text-decoration: none;
   vertical-align: middle;
}
.button:hover {
   border-top-color: orange;
   background: orange;
   color: white;
}
.button:active {
   border-top-color: orange;
   background: orange;
   color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sidebar-box">
  <p>malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
      <p>malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
      <p>malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
      <p>malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
      <p>malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
      <p>malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.Sanduiche de Presunto</p>
<p>Sanduiche de Presunto</p>    

  <p class="read-more"><a href="#" class="button">Read More</a></p>
</div>
```

Comment: "*Sanduiche de Presunto*" :)

Answer (score 1):

```js
var $el, $ps, $up, totalHeight;

$(".sidebar-box .button").click(function() {
      
  totalHeight = 0

  $el = $(this);
  $p  = $el.parent();
  $up = $p.parent();
  $ps = $up.find("p:not('.read-more')");
  
  // measure how tall inside should be by adding together heights of all inside paragraphs (except read-more paragraph)
  $ps.each(function() {
    totalHeight += $(this).outerHeight();
  });
    
  $up
    .css({
      // Set height to prevent instant jumpdown when max height is removed
      "min-height": totalHeight+(totalHeight/2)-100,
      "height": 'auto'
     // "max-height": 9999
    })
    .animate({
      "height": totalHeight
    });
  
  // fade out read-more
  $p.fadeOut();
  
  // prevent jump-down
  return false;
    
});
```

```css
.sidebar-box {
  max-height: 150px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.sidebar-box .read-more { 
  position: absolute; 
  bottom: 0; 
  left: 0;
  width: 100%; 
  text-align: center; 
  margin: 0; padding: 30px 0; 
 
  /* "transparent" only works here because == rgba(0,0,0,0) */
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent, white);
}

.button {
   /*border-top: 1px solid #96d1f8;*/
   background: #FF9C00;
   /*background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#FF9C00), to(#ffce80));
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #FF9C00, #ffce80);*/
   padding: 5px 10px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
   -moz-border-radius: 5px;
   border-radius: 5px;
   
   
   /* overboard shadows for Opera (and why spec version listed first) */
   box-shadow: rgba(196, 196, 196, 1) 0 1px 10px, rgba(196, 196, 196, 1) 0 0 10px, rgba(196, 196, 196, 1) 0 0 10px, rgba(0,0,0,90) 0 0 10px;
   
   -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
   -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
    
   text-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,.4) 0 1px 0;
   color: white;
   font-size: 15px;
   font-family: Georgia, serif;
   text-decoration: none;
   vertical-align: middle;
}
.button:hover {
   border-top-color: orange;
   background: orange;
   color: white;
}
.button:active {
   border-top-color: orange;
   background: orange;
   color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sidebar-box">
  <p>malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
      <p>malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
      <p>malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
      <p>malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
      <p>malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
      <p>malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.Sanduiche de Presunto</p>
<p>Sanduiche de Presunto</p>    
    <p>malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.Sanduiche de Presunto</p>
<p>Sanduiche de Presunto</p>    
    <p>malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.Sanduiche de Presunto</p>
<p>Sanduiche de Presunto</p>    
    <p>malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.Sanduiche de Presunto</p>
<p>Sanduiche de Presunto</p>    
    <p>malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.Sanduiche de Presunto</p>
<p>Sanduiche de Presunto</p>    
    <p>malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.Sanduiche de Presunto</p>
<p>Sanduiche de Presunto</p>    
    <p>malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.Sanduiche de Presunto</p>
<p>Sanduiche de Presunto</p>    
    <p>malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.Sanduiche de Presunto</p>
<p>Sanduiche de Presunto</p>    
    <p>malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.Sanduiche de Presunto</p>
<p>Sanduiche de Presunto</p>    
    <p>malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.Sanduiche de Presunto</p>
<p>Sanduiche de Presunto</p>    
    <p>malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.Sanduiche de Presunto</p>
<p>Sanduiche de Presunto 23123123</p>    
        <p>malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.Sanduiche de Presunto</p>
<p>Sanduiche de Presunto 23123123</p>  
        <p>malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.Sanduiche de Presunto</p>
<p>Sanduiche de Presunto 23123123</p>  
        <p>malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.Sanduiche de Presunto</p>
<p>Sanduiche de Presunto 9999999</p>  

  <p class="read-more"><a href="#" class="button">Read More</a></p>
</div>
```

O problema encontra-se quando defines o 'Height' no $up.css, se experimentar trocar aquele pedaço de código pelo seguinte, funciona corretamente.

```
 .css({
      // Set height to prevent instant jumpdown when max height is removed
      "min-height": totalHeight+(totalHeight/2)-100,
      "height": 'auto'
     // "max-height": 9999
```